How to access UserUnits (page scaling factor) on pdfcpu
Write PDF processing using pdfcpu library. Read and gather PDF info. Starting from v1.6 PDF page has Page Scaling Factor property. This field is used quite rarely, but I have files using it.
I get page boxes and almost everything is correct. However, there are a few pages that use UserUnits and the sizes are incorrect, these are the sizes I see in Adobe Acrobat and PDFX-Change, but how do I get them or UserUnits with pdfcpu?
dims, err := api.PageDimsFile("1.pdf")
    if err != nil { 
        fmt.Println("Cant open file")
        return
    }

but this code doesn't utilize UserUnits (Page Scaling Factor).
Output from pdfcpu utility
C:\src\go\pdfpagessizes>pdfcpu box list 2_1.pdf
listing mediaBox, cropBox, trimBox, bleedBox, artBox for 2_1.pdf
Page 1: rot=+0 orientation:landscape
  MediaBox (points) (0.00, 0.00, 4782.12, 1699.44) w=4782.12 h=1699.44 ar=2.81
   CropBox (points) (6.60, 5.41, 4775.16, 1692.84) w=4768.56 h=1687.43 ar=2.83
   TrimBox (points) (6.60, 5.41, 4775.16, 1692.84) w=4768.56 h=1687.43 ar=2.83 (default)
  BleedBox (points) (6.60, 5.41, 4775.16, 1692.84) w=4768.56 h=1687.43 ar=2.83 (default)
    ArtBox (points) (6.60, 5.41, 4775.16, 1692.84) w=4768.56 h=1687.43 ar=2.83 (default)
    >>>
    <Rotate, 0>
    <Type, Page>
    <UserUnit, 2>

but Adobe Acrobat says 9537,1 x 3374,9 pt and Enfocus Inspector show Page Scaling Factor: 2

Formally, the behavior of the library is not an error, there is no reason to create an issue, but it is not clear how to get to the UserUnit field when reading a file, despite the fact that when creating a pdf file entry, pdfcpu includes a UserUnit for each page in the file. This is not so much a library bug/problem as my lack of understanding of how to use

https://cloud.mail.ru/public/VvoY/j6vmZ2VVZ - 4A0 paper size This is a rather rare case of using UserUnit from the huge array of files I have. However, not the only one.

I need answer to single question - how can I get UserUnit value of page using pdfcpu. I dont need info how translate dimensions (boxes) using it

it doesn't matter, in this case, the issue was access to the UserUnit, this file just an useless example.
My quiestion is about pdfcpu api for golang, not about pdfcpu utility/

I have 2 versions of same utility for pdf processing, one version written on js under Acrobat Pro and second on Python. But I want to write fast standalone version of that program and I try to write it on golang using pdfcpu api. Everithing works well but Single problem - pages uses UserUnit > 1 and wrong size of boxes

You are not answering the question that I am asking. Thank you, but your answers are irrelevant

I know perfectly well how and where these sizes are formed, I work with pdf 25+ years, the question is not this, but how to get the userUnit value for the page using the pdfcpu api. Your answers are not relevant to my question
